# Using Comparison operators with DateTime datatype

Tags: datetime, biztalk

I am new C# and don't know how can I compare the `DateTime` datatype. If I am using equality operator it works fine:

```
RM(FILE.FileCreationTime) == System.DateTime.Parse("11:30:00")
```

But I shows me error when I use:

```
RM(FILE.FileCreationTime) <= System.DateTime.Parse("11:30:00")
```

Error is like:

> operator <= cannot be applied to the Operands of type System.DateTime and System.DateTime

Comment: Your code should work fine.  What is `RM`?

Comment: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,1301

Comment: this expression I am using in Biztalk Server. RM is the Filename

Comment: RM(FILE.FileCreationTime) is DateTime == true?

Comment: What is the EXACT error?

Comment: RM(FILE.FileCreationTime) is DateTime and it works perfectly with == operator

Comment: @rene operator <= cannot be applied to the Operands of type System.DateTime and System.DateTime

Comment: That is not the error. For one thing, using exact punctuation, the error reads `Operator '<=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T1' and 'T2'`, with `T1` and `T2` type names. You've posted a message that's almost but not quite like that. `System.DateTime` definitely is comparable using operator `<=`, therefore, either you are not using the `System.DateTime` type we all know and love (peculiar version of .NET?), or your error isn't exactly right. Does `global::System.DateTime x = RM(FILE.FileCreationTime);` compile?

Comment: This is in a shape on BizTalk?

Comment: yes on a Rule shape of Biztalk

Comment: Be advised that BizTalk scripting does not use C#.  It uses a variation of C# called XLang.  All of the features of C# may not be available in orchestration shapes or in rule scripts.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway is correct. Please also be adviced that the language in BizTalk orchestrations is also referred to as X#. The C# tag on your question is incorrect and I will propose an edit to remove it from your question.

Please see my answer below for a possible solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Important here that the syntax you are using is actually NOT c#!!
When working in BizTalk orchestrations you are using X#, a variation of C# based on [XLANG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa577463.aspx).

More information you can find here: http://masteringbiztalkserver.wordpress.com/2011/02/21/debugging-
orchestrations-in-biztalk-server-2009-using-c-cs-file/

> An Orchestration *.odx file contains an XML file and code written in a
>   language specific to BizTalk called X#.
>
> You can easily find these, when you right click an orchestration and
>   open it with XML Editor or Notepad.
>
> XML Representation of the Orchestration is used by the Graphical
>   Designer to show the shapes on the screen.
>
> X# code is in turn converted to C# at runtime using XSharp.exe file
>   and this C# assembly will be executed.
>
> This C# file can be found inside
>   \obj\Debug\BizTalk\Xlang\File0.cs once the project is
>   built.

So, the c# tag actually is incorrect here and I would seriously consider removing it from your question.

Nevertheless, you have the issue in your BizTalk orchestration.

My advice: add a variable of type System.DateTime to your orchestration.
Next, assign your variable to this value: `RM(FILE.FileCreationTime).`

This will allow you to use the if command properly in your shape.

Comment: Apparently, this should not be confused with [X#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Sharp) the programming language as I learned.

Comment: I actually never heard of this myself. Valuable lesson here! Thank you! Edited the answer.

Comment: Nom sir... You are wrong to refer to XLANG as X#.  X# is a .Net language, but has nothing to do with XLANG or BizTalk.  X# home is here: https://www.xsharp.info/

Comment: I am not saying Xsharp en the x# used in BizTalk are the same. The name x# was used as to make clear that the language was used in BizTalk orchestrations was a subset of c#. They are two different things actually.

Answer (score 1):

Late - but I stumbled upon this while looking for the same answer. The way to compare two `System.DateTime` objects in a BizTalk expression shape, is to use:

```
System.DateTime.Compare(DateTime1, DateTime2)
```

With `> 0, = 0 or < 0`...

And in the specified case

```
!(System.DateTime.Compare(RM(FILE.FileCreationTime), System.DateTime.Parse("11:30:00")) > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if (StartDate < EndDate)
// code
```

if you want to compare dates, and not the time

```
if (StartDate.Date < EndDate.Date)
// code
```